# Does GUID (Uniqueidentifier) in ASP .Net ever conflict?

Tags: c#, guid, uniqueidentifier

Is it possible GUID to conflict?

Actually i am generating GUID from two different applications and merge it in other database.

So, GUID column to be unique, Is there any chance it to be conflict?

Comment: I am not quite sure how these edits made anything remotely better.  Did you just pick random words to <code>?

Comment: Rolled back invalid edit.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on **how you created the `Guid`s**. If you use correct procedures (`Guid.NewGuid()` in .NET), it should be so staggeringly *unlikely* that they collide that you don't need to worry about it, unless you have enough time to keep generating them that the sun expanding and destroying the earth is a more immediate concern. Planetary destruction can play havoc with the unique constraints on your database.

However, here's a `Guid`: "000...0120" (all ... are zeros); here's another: "000...0120". In this case: definitely not unique.

Comment: So, should i generate GUID from a single application ?

Comment: @SohelPathan no, I didn't say that. It shouldn't matter how many computers, processes, app-domains, applications, etc are generating guids. What matters is *how* they are generating guids.

Comment: I am generating GUID using Guid.NewGuid() in my C# Code. and store in SQL database for userId field with type = uniqueidentifier. Other database is of MS-Access and SQL lite, these  are also generating UserIds. After that i have a synchronization process in which, i am merging all the UserIds. So can they collide?